# Minecraft Java and Pocket Edition differences

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition, version-differences

Why are Minecraft: Java Edition and Minecraft: Pocket Edition so different in game rules, mob behavior, redstone mechanics etc? It's really frustrating when I search, for example, for a good iron farm design, find one and make it on PE just to find out that it doesn't work. Then I find a huge design for PE which I don't want to build because I'm lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PE was never a branch of JE - it was a complete rewrite from scratch in different language, for different platforms, and initially vastly simplified in relation to JE - it was meant to run on definitely underpowered at the time smartphones. It was really bare-bones, probably simpler than Minecraft from times of Alpha.

JE from the beginning had the benefit of a fairly strong PC so it could afford quite a few liberties PE just couldn't.

Ever since, the development of PE tried to bring it somewhat closer to JE but it's still running on underpowered devices, every feature still needs to be reimplemented from scratch (different programming language!) and many idiosyncrasies of each conflict with each other and are kept for 'legacy' reasons, so for example neither will PE adapt quasi-connectivity nor will JE drop it.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but my computer is a bit slow, so i prefer playing on PE. I know that it does not change anything, I'm just saying.

Comment: Are we talking about Pocket Edition or Bedrock Edition currently? Because right now they are still two different things. There's no PE for PC.

Comment: Bedrock and PE are the same platform, built on C++. And yes, you can get the Bedrock Edition on Windows 10 from the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Bedrock branched off from PE and progressed to a much closer parity to JE (although it has still significant differences.) PE still functions independently from BE on mobile devices and the differences are massive.

Comment: @SF. So Minecraft Pocket Edition still exists as a separate of Bedrock Edition? If so, where?